# Django+Bokeh+autoload_server : get one div by figure

Tags: python, django, bokeh

Using Bokeh 0.12.4 and django 1.10.6, how can I obtain a `script` for individual `figure` by using `autoload_server`.

In `myapp/main.py`:

```
from bokeh.plotting import Figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc
fig1= Figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=300, name='fig1')
fig2 = Figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=300, name='fig2')
curdoc().add_root(fig1)
curdoc().add_root(fig2)
```

In `mysite/views.py`, I would like to do something like that:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from bokeh.embed import autoload_server
def index(request):
    script1 = autoload_server(model='fig1', url="http://localhost:5006/myapp")     
    script2 = autoload_server(model='fig2', url="http://localhost:5006/myapp")                        
    return render(request, 'index.html', context={'script1': script1, 'script2': script2})
```

And then put the scripts where I want in the html template `mysite/templates/index.html`:

```
<div>
    {{script1 | safe }}
</div>

<div>
    {{script2 | safe }}
</div>
```

Comment: did you solve that ??